# Choosing the correct power supply for the controller

Tags: microcontroller

For my project I need a Siemens controller. I can not choose one. And the problem is not about amount of  i/o pins or aviable programming blocks. I dont know which power supply characteristics will be best for me (24 AC/24DC or even 220 AC). In my control panel there is 220 AC everywhere. And maybe it is better to use a controller with 220 AC power supply. But in other side I can use 220/24 transformer and use a 24 AC power supply controller. The second case seems to be more safer. 
How do you choose a controller in your projects? I repeat I ack only about power supply characteristics.  Is there any difference between theese two case except safety?

EDIT

To be more cleare I attached a picture. [image]

It is how I see this. When someting happens sensor says it to controller and then controller opens a relay. Relay opens a contactor and my motor runs.

As I understand I can not open a contactor directly by a controller. So I need a  relay. If Siemens controller output is 5 V and my contactor is openned by 25 V I need relay 5/25 V. And then I think "I need relay in any case. So I need transformer 220/25 V. And if I need this transformer then why I dont use this 25 V as power suply for my controller?". 
But also I can use relay 5/220 V. In this case I need not a transformer (if I use a controller with 220 power supply).

The best thing would be if I could control a contactor directly by a controller.

What is the best way? It is my first project with high vltages. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Do you mean that you already have a controller chosen (as suggested by "can not choose one"), or that you need to choose one (which the rest of the post suggests)? Generally, you'll want at least the sensor to be isolated from mains 220V (either by power supply outside of controller, or power supply inside the controller. Pay attention that power supply actually isolates from 220V, cheap/switched ones normally don't).

Comment: I have not a controller chosen. I asked what controlle will be better for my project (with 220 or 25 V power supple

Comment: And controllers, are they otherwise the same, just for the voltage supply difference? I'd expect them to have some internal PSU in this case. Datasheet links?

Comment: I want to buy a controller. The question is : is there any difference between controllers with 220 and 25 V power supply. If there is not any difference then I am free to choose without worring.